# Inconsistent number of samples K Nearest Neighbor sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I'm doing some self training on stuff from guidetodatamining.com and am working on some K Nearest Neightbor stuff using sklearn. I am getting the error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 20]

When I run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
cols= ['Name', 'Sport', 'Height', 'Weight']
df = pd.read_table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zacharski/pg2dm-python/master/data/ch4/athletesTrainingSet.txt",  names = cols, index_col='Name')
df = df[1:]
df = df[ ['Height', 'Weight','Sport'] ]
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)
X= df.Height, df.Weight
y = df.Sport
knn.fit(X, y)
knn.predict(X)
```

In the dataset there are 20 in each of the three rows so I have no idea whats happening.
I am trying to use the Height and Weight friends to help train the Sport field, so that if you put some data in it "recommends" what sport a person would play. I know theres several similar topic about the LinearRegression tool but I can't get any of the solutions on those to work for me. I have tried reshaping my data, and I have tried doing just height or weight but that gives me an error on a 1D instead of 2D array.

Even just a helpful nudge in the right direction would be incredibly helpful as I have been staring at this for 2 days now with no solution. Thank you.

Comment: I think you might need to take the transpose of your `X`, the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.fit) say that the shape is `[n_samples, n_features]` but I think yours is `[n_features, n_samples]`. You can probably use [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to take the transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your x,y creation. x is two pandas data series and y is just one serie. Creating two new dataframes can solve your problem. You can run your code line by line to locate it.

```
x= df[["Height","Weight"]]
y = df[["Sport"]]
```

You can try splitting your dataset into to sets. Your model can be train on one set and be validated in the other.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.predict(X_test)
```

You can save your target value and prediction into a dataframe and check them.

```
comp_results=pd.concat([y_test,pd.DataFrame(data=knn.predict(X_test),index=y_test.index.values.tolist())],axis =1).rename(columns={"Sport":"Target",0:"Prediction"})
```